# Issue with docker + springboot + aws sqs

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, amazon-sqs

I have a api in docker, and when i try to run the docker always get the next error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taxesController' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/xxxxxx/xxxxx/fitness/taxes/rest/XxxxxController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taxesService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/fitness/xxxxxxxx/service/XxxxxxService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'historyService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/fitness/xxxxxxx/service/XxxxxxService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SQSProducerService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/fitness/sqs/service/SQSProducerService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonSQSAsync' defined in class path resource [com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/fitness/config/SQSConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync]: Factory method 'amazonSQSAsync' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname cannot be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.FitnessApplication.main(FitnessApplication.java:22)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taxesService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/fitness/xxxxxx/service/XxxxxService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'historyService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/fitness/xxxxxxx/service/HistoryService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor paramete
```

That is my application.yml (I was tried with the name of image, with localhost, with the ip in network from docker...)

```
cloud:
  aws:
    stack:
      auto: false
    region:
      static: eu-central-1
    credentials:
      access-key: MyAPIKEY
      secret-key: MySecretKey
    end-point:
      uri: http://172.18.0.3:4566
sqs:
  history:
    url: http://172.18.0.3:4566/000000000000/local_material_deportivo_fitness_history
    name: local_fitness_history
```

I was tried with the name of image, with localhost, with the ip in network from docker... always got the same error. (sorry for my english)

Comment: I think your end-point.uri is wrong. It should be something like `https://sqs.us-central-1.amazonaws.com/<some id>/<queue name>`

Comment: I try with your recommendations and have the same error. In my local computer work very fine (using IntelijIDEA with docker). In this machine, this case i try to use a localstack with a machine for dev enviroments